# Production build Vue js, can't access the image file in the build folder

Tags: vue.js, build, production

I ve created a vue 3 project

and I have this code where I'm creating a div using jquery.

```
     var div = $(
          `<div data-v-3230242e data-item_index='${itemm.index}' data-itemid_name='${item_name}' data-sqlid='${itemm.id}' draggable=true class="itemImage"></div>`
        );
        div.css(
          "background-image",
          "url(" + `/assets/images/${item_name}.png` + ")"
        );
        console.log("ééé");
        let container = $(`#mainBar .backbag_inventory #${box.id}`);
        console.log(container);
        container.append(div);
```

PS: When i'm runing npm run serve ( the vue server) everything works fine.

So I checked that the div is created but its background image cannot be set.

This is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: './',
    filenameHashing: false,
    lintOnSave: false,
    outputDir: '../client_packages/gamemode/vuebrowser'
}
```

I have some static divs, however its background image are set.
divs css:

```
#backbag {
  background: url("../../assets/images/backbagstatic.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 95% auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: rgba(7, 10, 22, 0.796);
}
```

I tried those with the urls too but couldn't get it to work :

```
"url(" + `../../assets/images/${item_name}.png` + ")"  
"url(" + `./assets/images/${item_name}.png` + ")"
```

And the builded folder is this:
[Build Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK3gl.png)

Please can anyone had the issue before, help me and thank you

Comment: For CSS you should use something like: `--bg-image: url("~assets/img/fondosCurrentWeather/campo-nubes-movil.jpg")`. '~' means from '/src/'. Keep in mind that this is loaded by webpack.

Comment: tried it , only worked  in npm run serve